# How to calculate the shortest interval between 2 datetime columns in minutes

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say that I have a table with a DateTime column, for example, Order_time and another DateTime column Return_time and I want to calculate the smallest time difference for each store between the shortest interval (in min) from purchase to return time?

```
CREATE TABLE `Transactions` (
  'store_id' text,
  'buyer_id' integer,
  'item_id' integer,
  'order_time' datetime,
  'return_time' datetime

);
```

How do I use Datediff() in this case?

Comment: SELECT  store_id FROM Transactions tr GROUP BY DESC HAVING Datediff(tr.order_time, tr.return_time )

Comment: what timezone are these times in?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Store_Id, MIN(DATEDIFF(mi, order_time, return_time))
FROM Transactions
GROUP BY Store_Id
```

Comment: I think you mean `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, ...`?

Comment: Since they are datetime fields DATEDIFF would work in Sql server